# Help recognizing partial differential equation

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-equations

I would be  very grateful if someone could tell me something about the following partial differential equation:

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} = K * (\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial r^2} + (1/r)\frac{\partial U}{\partial r}).
$$

A friend told me that the equation models the [heat equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation), but I don't think he is right.

Any help?

Comment: Your friend is right, you might want to check the definition of [$\nabla^2$ in **cylindrical** coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) with the added assumption that $U$ is independent of $\phi,\,z$. That said, what more are you wanting to know about this equation?

Answer (score 5):

That is the heat equation in polar coordinates with axial symmetry. The (isotropic) heat equation without sources or sinks is

$$
\frac{\partial U}{\partial t} - K\nabla^2U =0.
$$

If you look up the Laplacian operator in cylindrical coordinates, you will find that your expression matches this exactly.

Comment: If this answers the question to your satisfaction, it is customary to "accept" the answer, so others don't waste time providing other explanations. Glad I could help!